# How to increase function by 1 using loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to run a loop that auto increase the function name by 1. For easier to understand:

My currently code:

```
 for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
                var fn = 'this.getExterior',
                    el = (fn + i + '()').getInnerItems();
}
```

I want to increase the function name and retrieve something like this.getExterior1 , this.getExterior2. The above code give me an object not a function. Can someone give me a solution how to achieve it. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really use strings as code (`eval` can but it's not necessary here). You can use the `[]` syntax:

```
el = this["getExterior" + i]().getInnerItems();
```

(Also, `function` is a keyword; you cannot use it as a variable name.)

Answer (score 2):

it will be :

```
var el = this['getExterior'+i]().getInnerItems();
```

in javascript any property or object can be accessed this way

`object.property` is the same as `object['property']`

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following:

```
var i, fn;

for (i = 1; i <= 2; ++i) {
  fn = 'getExterior' + i;
  el = this[fn]().getInnerItems();
}
```